# OpenGL - Objects shake when camera moves or rotates

Tags: opengl, camera, simulation, transformation, visual-glitch

I have attached a camera object to a mobile object (a car) at a scene. The camera shows the area which the object is at and looking to (front window of the car).

My problem is that, while my object (with camera) moves or rotates, the objects at the screen (street light sticks, other cars moving parallel) seem shaking. Namely I see the solid object and some little transparent versions of the same object near to the original. It is more observable when the camera changes its orientation than when it moves straight. When moving straight, the lights shake when they are far from the observer, at some range they stop shaking, and when they get nearer they start shaking again.

I do not think that OpenGL makes a motion blur at the background by itself. But I also could not find a name to this problem, so I am not able to find a starting point.

Comment: Are you doing the double-buffering correctly?

Comment: Actually, I am using Presagis's LynX Prime utility. I know about double buffering (so do not be so quick to downgrade the question). **I do not think the problem to be such simple!** But may be.. I just realized that when I use Motion Walk as the motion strategy, the screen is smooth, but when I use Motion Game, the objects oscillates.

Comment: I want to give one more information about the case. Think a box with one white side and one dark gray side and we see both sides. When I get near to the object and move to the left and right, so the objects go to the left and right of the screen, the colors are entering to each other a bit. I opened vsync of both the application and the driver, and adapted settings of driver to favor visuality. I will deeply investigate the double buffering issued.

Comment: According to my talks with some friends, the topic is related to vsync and refresh rate of the monitors. I am accepting the problem as is and will not invest on its solution anymore.

Comment: I have solved the problem. When the program is in full screen mode, and the time required to draw the full scene is below 16msec (for 60fps), then I could be able to have smooth movement with no objects oscillating. When the draw time oscillates too much or when I set Vega to limit the fps algorithmically, the scene oscillates. When I set the swap interval to 1, namely letting the underlying draw thread to match with screen refresh, then it is fine again.

Comment: That sounds good enough to be an answer; please move your comment to an answer and mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the program is in full screen mode, and the time required to draw the full scene is below 16msec (for 60fps), then I could be able to have smooth movement with no objects oscillating.

When the draw time oscillates too much or when I set Vega to limit the fps algorithmically, the scene oscillates.

When I set the swap interval to 1, namely letting the underlying draw thread to match with screen refresh, then it is fine again.